# How to make rounded box and shaded background behind text in Latex?

Tags: moderncv, backgrounds, cv, shapes

I am trying to create a following image in `LaTeX` for my resume. I can find a lot of questions and answers being discussed on the perfect rectangular background but not the rounded shape.
[image]

Comment: There are many, many such questions on this site that already have answers.  Look for the `tcolorbox` package, for example here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251145/how-to-change-the-size-of-rounded-corner-of-beamer-blocks

Comment: oh! they are called beamer blocks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{shadedcvbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,colback=white!60!blue,boxrule=0pt,arc=2mm,auto outer arc,boxsep=0pt,coltext={blue},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadedcvbox}
Employment Experience
\end{shadedcvbox}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{shadedcvbox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=white!80!blue,
  coltext={blue},
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=3mm,
  auto outer arc,
  boxsep=3pt,
  left=4pt,
  right=2pt,
  bottom=2pt,
  top=2pt,
  fontupper={\bfseries},
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadedcvbox}
Employment Experience
\end{shadedcvbox}

\begin{shadedcvbox}[colback=yellow!80!white,coltext={red},drop fuzzy shadow={yellow!80!black}]
Employment Experience
\end{shadedcvbox}

\begin{shadedcvbox}[interior style={left color=blue!20!white, right color=yellow!50!white}]
Employment Experience
\end{shadedcvbox}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `arc=4mm` would be better... and `white!90!blue`... and `\sffamily`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: The `arc=` size depends on the real content, in my point of view and is also subject to opinion. I took some arbitrary color value to show the possibilities

Comment: I want to slightly decrease the margin for the beamer box so I can have all the text align nicely on left side. How do I override the margins just for the box so I can slightly decrease it for the box and have my text align together. Currently my text "employment experience" is slightly shifted to the right compare to other text in my resume.

Comment: @DhruvPatel `slightly` isn't a very precise value. Change the `left=...` value then

Comment: I meant to decrease box margin about half centimeter. The left = ... Moves the text to left but the box isn't moving. I want the box sides to move which isn't changing.

Comment: @DhruvPatel: Ah, the box should move... Use `left skip=-0.2cm` and perhaps `right skip=0.2cm` too. Change the skip value to your needs