# rounded box around text

Tags: rounded-corners

```
 \newcommand*\round[2]{%
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
\node[anchor=north west, draw,rectangle ,rounded corners, inner xsep=5.6cm,
 minimum size=5.5mm, height=3.6mm, fill=#2,#2,text=white,align= left](char){#1};
%
}
```

[image]

I am getting this, but I need the text to be left aligned and the round boxes to be the same size.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you aware of the `tcolorbox` package?

Answer (score 2):

I have changed some of your parameters and condensed them to what you need. Keep in mind that `text width` is what you needed (you don't have to use `align = left` because it is set to left by default).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\round[2]{\par
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[draw = #1, fill = #1, rectangle, rounded corners, 
              minimum size = 5.5mm, text = white, text width = 10cm](char){#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par%
}%
\begin{document}
    \round{blue}{First Title}
    some text\\
    \round{red}{Second Title}
    some text\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I think the following addresses your requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\round[2][blue]{%
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[shape=rectangle,
rounded corners, minimum width=\textwidth,text width=\textwidth-3em, 
minimum  height=2em,text depth=0.3em,
 fill=#1,text=white,align=left,font=\sffamily](char){#2};%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\round{Some text}

\noindent
\round[blue!70!black]{Some other text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I feel you might be better off using `tcolorbox`, which is based on `tikz`. Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276248/121799) you may do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{rounded}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,colback=blue,
boxrule=0pt,arc=2mm,auto outer arc,boxsep=0pt,coltext={white},fontupper=\sffamily,
#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{rounded}
Some text
\end{rounded}

\begin{rounded}[colback=blue!70!black]
Some more text
\end{rounded}
\end{document}
```

[image]